# Is it possible to send text directly to the clip board in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I know that it is possible to copy text from some sort of editable control in the DOM, via getElementById, to the clip board in JavaScript (see the link below). But is it possible to send from a JavaScript string variable directly to the clip board? I'm interested in doing this in a browser extension, so that may have more security restrictions for JavaScript in this case.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't possible. There are some libraries that achieve it using Flash, but that's going away soon.

Comment: @Barmar so whatever you want to put on the clip board has to go via an editable control, right?

Comment: I used this once - works well: https://clipboardjs.com/

Comment: Here's an MDN page on interacting with the clipboard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard

Answer (score 0):

You said you're trying to do this in a browser extension, so yes your extension can access the user's clipboard if you've been granted that permission.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard

Note that you don't need permission to use the copy command in short-lived user initiated events like click events.

```js
document.execCommand("copy")
```

However, if you are wanting to have more options on how and when you can access the user's clipboard, you will need additional permissions. That same page above mentions using the Clipboard API for this

> The Clipboard API adds greater flexibility, in that you aren't limited to simply copying the current selection into the clipboard, but can directly specify what information to place into the clipboard.

They provide a function which does exactly that:

```js
function updateClipboard(newClip) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(newClip).then(function() {
    /* clipboard successfully set */
  }, function() {
    /* clipboard write failed */
  });
}
```

And another function to check if you have permission to write to the clipboard:

```js
navigator.permissions.query({name: "clipboard-write"}).then(result => {
  if (result.state == "granted" || result.state == "prompt") {
    /* write to the clipboard now */
  }
});
```